# Differentiate between application launch and application awake

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, nsnotifications, uiapplication

I need to be able to differentiate between application didFinishLaunching and application entering background and being loaded back into the foreground. I noticed that  if I register for the UIApplicationDidBecomeActiveNotification, it is called in both instances. How do I distinguish between the two?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I need to be able to differentiate between application
>   didFinishLaunching

```
UIApplicationDidFinishLaunchingNotification
```

> application entering background

```
UIApplicationDidEnterBackgroundNotification
```

> being loaded back into the foreground

```
UIApplicationWillEnterForegroundNotification
```

Answer (score 4):

Use the `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions` vs `applicationWillEnterForeground` to distinguish if app is starting cold or returning from background.

I tried listening to the UINotification's in one of my apps, but the notification was being delivered too late, so I resorted to listening to these method calls directly.

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
    // only call when app is freshly launched
}

- (void)applicationWillEnterForeground:(UIApplication *)application
{
    // Only called when app is returning from background
}
```

Comment: I need to know this outside the app delegate.. does this mean ill have to set up notifications manually? i'd expect there to be preexisting notifications for these...

Comment: @user1492272 - Yes, there are notifications to listen to all of the app state changes, but it didn't work for me because they were delivered too late, at least in my case. Actually I remember now why I didn't use them - it was a very specific case. I wanted to reset the UI if the app was returning from background after a day or so. The notification was getting delivered after the view from the previous day was already on-screen, at which point mucking around with the UI and resetting the app state would've been abrupt and wasn't an option for me. So I had to listen directly to the method calls